# Can an init function in golang return a value?

Tags: go

Can any one suggest any another approach to deal with initializing a database outside init function in my server.go program ?

I am using a MySQL in my program and it is my requirement to initialize and connect and send the handler to the controllers.

Comment: It is always good to support your question with code. And from your question it is not clear as to what issue are you facing while initializing DB in init method and why you want another approach outside init method

Comment: You don't have initialize you db from `init` function. You can initialize from the `main()` function which calls your `initDB()`, I guess

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return a value with the `init()` function but what you can do is initialize global(package) variables with it so you can try something like that:

```
package mysql

var Conn Connection

func init(){
    Conn = ...
}
```

And now the controllers can access your connection importing your package and accessing your already initialized connection.

```
package controllers

import(
    "mysql"
)

func abc(){
    mysql.Conn ...
}
```